# What does make -jn mean?

Tags: centos, make, llvm

I am trying to install LLVM on my CentOS machine.
In the installation tutorial of LLVM, a  flag `-jn` is specified along with `make`.

It says to perform `make -jn` and also says "**Choose n such that make doesn’t run in to swap space issue.**"

What is the use of the `-j` flag and how can I choose the value of n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-j` make flag denotes how many threads you want to allot for compiling.

`n` is, in this case, a place-holder for the number of processes.

The classic rule of thumb is that it's safe to make `n` = the number of cores your CPU has. So if you are on a dual core machine, you might use `-j2`, while on an 8-core machine `-j8`

In practise, I have found that to be a good starting place, but you should probably feel free to experiment a bit and see what works best for you.

Comment: I like cores + 1

Comment: Won't it be processes not threads in a strict sense?

Comment: yes good point @heemayl

Comment: Cores+1 is usually a better option: it lets you have one process stalled on disk I/O while still fully utilizing your CPU.

Comment: `-j$(nproc)` to always give it the number of cores the system has.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's safe to use n = number of cores also depends on whether you have enough memory for all the parallel compile/link jobs. It could also cause issues for disk I/O. If this is a make job you only expect to need to run once it's probably better to choose a lower n and just let it take its time.

Answer (score 2):

The `-j` flag tells `make(1)` how many processes to run in parallel. Best value depends on the tasks run, dependencies, ... a rule of thumb is the number of processors. If you give just `-j` (no `n`), `make` starts as many processes in parallel as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a concrete example of how the `-j` flag affects a build operation and a reason to be careful with it:

I forgot I had `MAKEFLAGS=-j5` and tried to build LLVM; once it reached `97%` percent it spawned 5 `ld` processes at the same time, each consuming `1.5GB`+ RAM. The first one crashed within 20 minutes, and the rest kept consuming more and more memory until my computer was unusable and I finally decided to `Ctrl+C` it and try again with a smaller `-j`. With `-j3` my computer is still struggling with three `ld` processes but at least I can still type this with  only a few hiccups.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this experience. It's helpful